# Data is inserted twice from android emulator to mysql

Tags: php, android

I am inserting data from my Android Emulator to **MySQL** by using **PHP**. When data is inserted, it is inserted two times.I tried with postman but data is inserted only once. I guess the fault is in my java code.

Follow is my java code

```
public class URLs {
    private static final String ROOT_URL = "http://10.0.2.2:8888/MyPHPMYSQL/MyApi.php?apicall=";
    public static final String URL_INSERTDATA = ROOT_URL + "insertdata";
    public static final String URL_LOGIN= ROOT_URL + "login";
}

public class RequestHandler {
    public String sendPostRequest(String requestURL, HashMap<String, String> postDataParams) {
        URL url;

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            url = new URL(requestURL);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(15000);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);

            OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();

            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(getPostDataString(postDataParams));
            Log.i("44444", "sendPostRequest: "+getPostDataString(postDataParams));

           writer.flush();
           writer.close();
           os.close();
            int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();

            if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

                String response="";
                Log.i("gh444ghg", "sendPostRequest: "+conn.getInputStream());

                while ((response = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(response);
                    Log.i("ghghg", "sendPostRequest: "+response);

                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.i("ghghg", "sendPostRequest: "+sb.toString());
        return sb.toString();
    }


    //this method is converting keyvalue pairs data into a query string as needed to send to the server
    private String getPostDataString(HashMap<String, String> params) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        boolean first = true;
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet()) {
            if (first)
                first = false;
            else
                result.append("&");

            result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
            result.append("=");
            result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
        }

        return result.toString();
    }
}
```

On button click in my Main Activity i am calling  AsyncTask class

```
new RegisterUser().execute();

class RegisterUser extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

            private ProgressBar progressBar;
            final String yourname = yourName.getText().toString().trim();
            final String yourmobileno = yourMobileNo.getText().toString().trim();
            final String referralName1 = referralName.getText().toString().trim();
            final String referralContact1 = referralContact.getText().toString().trim();
            final String referralEmail1 = referralEmail.getText().toString().trim();
            final String loantype1 = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString().trim();
            final String loanamount1 = loanamount.getText().toString().trim();


            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
                //creating request handler object
             //   RequestHandler requestHandler = new RequestHandler();

                //creating request parameters
                HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("your_username", yourname);
                params.put("your_mobile", yourmobileno);
                params.put("referral_name", referralName1);
                params.put("referral_contact", referralContact1);
                params.put("referral_email", referralEmail1);
                params.put("loan_type", loantype1);
                params.put("loan_amount", loanamount1);

                //returing the response
                Log.i("pritish", "doInBackground: "+new RequestHandler().sendPostRequest(URLs.URL_INSERTDATA, params));

                return new RequestHandler().sendPostRequest(URLs.URL_INSERTDATA, params);
                   }

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                //displaying the progress bar while user registers on the server
                progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                super.onPostExecute(s);
                //hiding the progressbar after completion
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                try {
                    //converting response to json object
                    Log.i("jjj", "onPostExecute: "+s);
                    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(s);
                 //   JSONArray jsonArray=new JSONArray(s);
                  //  JSONObject obj=jsonArray.getJSONObject(s);

                    //if no error in response
                    if (!obj.getBoolean("error")) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), obj.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        //getting the user from the response
                        JSONObject userJson = obj.getJSONObject("user");

                        //creating a new user object
                        User user = new User(
                                userJson.getInt("id"),
                                userJson.getString("your_username"),
                                userJson.getString("your_mobile"),
                                userJson.getString("referral_name"),
                                userJson.getString("referral_contact"),
                                userJson.getString("referral_email"),
                                userJson.getString("loan_type"),
                                userJson.getString("loan_amount")
                        );

                        //starting the profile activity
                        //finish();
                        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), GetAllDataActivity.class));
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Some error occurred", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }


    }
```

Following is my php code

```
<?php
        //getting the database connection
 require_once 'MyDbConnect.php';

 //an array to display response
 $response = array();

 //if it is an api call
 //that means a get parameter named api call is set in the URL
 //and with this parameter we are concluding that it is an api call
 if(isset($_GET['apicall'])){

 switch($_GET['apicall']){

 case 'insertdata':
 //checking the parameters required are available or not
 if(isTheseParametersAvailable(array('your_username','your_mobile','referral_name','referral_contact',
'referral_email','loan_type','loan_amount'))){

 //getting the values
 $your_username = $_POST['your_username'];
 $your_mobile = $_POST['your_mobile'];
 $referral_name = $_POST['referral_name'];
 $referral_contact = $_POST['referral_contact'];
$referral_email = $_POST['referral_email'];
$loan_type = $_POST['loan_type'];
$loan_amount = $_POST['loan_amount'];


 //if user is new creating an insert query
 $stmt = "insert into mytable (your_username,your_mobile,referral_name,
 referral_contact,referral_email,loan_type,loan_amount
 ) values ('$your_username','$your_mobile','$referral_name','$referral_contact'
 ,'$referral_email','$loan_type','$loan_amount')";

$ext=mysqli_query($conn,$stmt);
 //if the user is successfully added to the database
 if($ext==true){
 //fetching the user back
 $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT id, your_username, your_mobile, referral_name,
  referral_contact,referral_email,loan_type,loan_amount  FROM mytable WHERE your_username = ?");
 $stmt->bind_param("s",$your_username);
 $stmt->execute();
 $stmt->bind_result($id, $your_username, $your_mobile, $referral_name,$referral_contact,
 $referral_email,$loan_type,$loan_amount);
 $stmt->fetch();

 $user = array(
 'id'=>$id,
 'your_username'=>$your_username,
 'your_mobile'=>$your_mobile,
 'referral_name'=>$referral_name,
 'referral_contact'=>$referral_contact,
 'referral_email'=>$referral_email,
 'loan_type'=>$loan_type,
 'loan_amount'=>$loan_amount
 );

 $stmt->close();

 //adding the user data in response
 $response['error'] = false;
 $response['message'] = 'Data inserted successfully';
 $response['user'] = $user;
 }

 }else{
 $response['error'] = true;
 $response['message'] = 'required parameters are not available';
 }



 break;

 default:
 $response['error'] = true;
 $response['message'] = 'Invalid Operation Called';
 }

 }else{
 //if it is not api call
 //pushing appropriate values to response array
 $response['error'] = true;
 $response['message'] = 'Invalid API Call';
 }

 //displaying the response in json structure
 echo json_encode($response);

function isTheseParametersAvailable($params){

 //traversing through all the parameters
 foreach($params as $param){
 //if the paramter is not available
 if(!isset($_POST[$param])){
 //return false
 return false;
 }
 }
 //return true if every param is available
 return true;
 }
?>
```

I have tried with the android emulator and whenever I insert data it is inserting twice.Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: Have you checked by removing this line Log.i("pritish", "doInBackground: "+new RequestHandler().sendPostRequest(URLs.URL_INSERTDATA, params));  May be this looks like not a appropriate answer but can't say anything regarding errors, but anything can happen in coding.

Comment: You're calling `sendPostRequest` twice: first in `Log.i` and then in `return`.

Comment: @PankajMundra It worked Man. Thanks alot. Wasted almost a day on it.

Comment: @FirstOne Thanks

Comment: No problem. You could store that value in a variable, Log the variable and return it. Or, Log the returned value from outside the function. **But**, maybe you're better off properly debugging the code, instead of just echoing things.

Comment: @AbuSawant please accept and upvote my answer.

Comment: @PankajMundra we are not meant to grub for upvotes like that.  Plus, the OP doesn't have the permission to upvote yet.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Removing this line

Log.i("pritish", "doInBackground: "+new RequestHandler().sendPostRequest(URLs.URL_INSERTDATA, params));

May be this looks like not a appropriate answer but can't say anything regarding errors, but anything can happen in coding.

Comment: I have flagged the question as _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a **simple typographical error**. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting._ I don't think it needs an answer.